# JAVA_HOME is set to the wrong directory

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft

Hello fellow Ubuntu users,

I am trying to learn how to write modifications to Minecraft. In order to follow the tutorial I am using, I need to run a "gradlew". The command is as follows

```
./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse
```

This yields the following

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

Obviously I don't know what to do or even what this means. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffe-nXX1hmU&t=91s

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Before running the command try entering:

`export JAVA_HOME="path_to_java_home"`

Where path_to_java_home is the folder where your bin/java is.

If java is properly installed you can find it's location, by using the command:

`readlink -f $(which java)`

Don't forget to remove bin/java from the end of the path while putting it into JAVA_HOME

Comment: Okay, I did what you said, however, it yields the same results except the path has changed.

Comment: If you run `$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version` after export, does it work fine showing the java version?

Comment: $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version yields bash: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_20/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: seems like your export is wrong. Please show export command you used. And also show the `readlink -f $(which java)` output

Comment: xport JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java" yields nothing (suggests it worked)

Comment: with the "e" at the beginning. I just posted wrong

Comment: you should set it to the folder where bin/java is meaning `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre"` not `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java"`

Answer (score 26):

To make it automatic on Linux/Ubuntu, add these lines at the end of your `.bashrc`:

```
JAVA_HOME=$(dirname $( readlink -f $(which java) ))
JAVA_HOME=$(realpath "$JAVA_HOME"/../)
export JAVA_HOME
```

This gets java executable, then climbs up a directory level

To designate the default java version/executable on Debian/Ubuntu, run this **once**:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This builds up on previous answer by Andrew Onischuk (thanks!)

Answer (score 3):

Get your Java path using the command

```
whereis java
```

The following is a possible output depending on your default Java version

```
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/bin/java
```

Maven need to pick the Java location (home) so you can export the Java path using the following command

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre
```

This will allow Maven to pick the java version and location in the /etc/environment file

Optionally you can add this in the /etc/environment manually using the following command

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

and edit the `JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_241/jre/`

Comment: There is no jre in jdk-17-oracle-x64 ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Try to edit /usr/bin/gradle

Comment the line "export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java" with a #

this: #export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java

Comment: But if default-java is using the wrong java version, how do you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Run with sudo

```
sudo ./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse
```

You are not a sudo doer for running this command

So Add **sudo** to it.